# Cross-validation predictions for lightGBM

Tags: r, cross-validation, grid-search, ensemble-learning, lightgbm

Is there a simple way to recover cross-validation predictions from the model built using `lgb.cv` from `lightGBM`?

I am doing a grid search combined with cross validation. Ultimately I would like to obtain the predictions for each of the defined hold-out folds so I can also stack a few models.

Answer (score 1):

the only way i have found is to continue to train (`lgb.train`) the same model (booster) to do this you must use `init_model='model.txt'`. Then save the models best iteration like this `bst.save_model('model.txt', num_iteration=bst.best_iteration)`. Note this is python api, sorry. I have asked the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667598/saving-the-best-iteration-of-a-python-lightgbm-built-in-cross-validation-model) but for the python api